# How to add common variable into a JSON Selenium builder test suite?

Tags: json, selenium, testing, builder, suite

I'd like to add a variable into each test, for example `${url}`.
Into a single test, this is the JSON code:

```
    "data": {
    "configs": {
      "manual": {
        "url": "https://my_url"
      }
    },
    "source": "manual"
  },
```

I want to share `${url}` variable with all my tests. How should i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Selenium Builder wiki under [Data driven Testing](https://github.com/SeleniumBuilder/se-builder/wiki/Data-driven-Testing) you can store variables as an array of objects.

For your use you will make the file look like this:

```
[
    {"url" : "https://my_url"}
]
```

save the file as test_values.json in the same folder as your test and reference it like this in your test.json:

```
"data": {
"configs": {
  "json": {
    "path": "test_values.json"
  }
},
"source": "json"
},
```

If you need to pass multiple variables to your test do it inside the object (the curly braces) like this:

```
[
    {
        "url" : "https://my_url",
        "user" : "some_user",
        "password" : "some_password"
    }
]
```

Now, the fun part is, that if you add another object (set of curly braces) like this:

```
[
    {
        "url" : "https://my_url",
        "user" : "some_user",
        "password" : "some_password"
    },
    {
        "url" : "https://my_url",
        "user" : "some_other_user",
        "password" : "some_other_password"
    }
]
```

Then the test will run twice. Once with the first set of values, and the second time with the second set of values.